# Trying to make keybinding in spacemacs

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs

I'm trying to bind ",," to eval the topmost S-expression containing the cursor in common lisp layer, from [this](http://develop.spacemacs.org/doc/DOCUMENTATION.html#binding-keys) page I assumed it would be done like so:

```
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys-for-major-mode 'common-lisp-mode "," 'slime-eval-defun)
```

Which returns `nil`, but when I try to use it, says it's undefined.

Thinking that "," may be special in some way I tried this:

```
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys-for-major-mode 'common-lisp-mode "eh" 'slime-eval-defun)
```

with the same outcome.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I had to assign it for `lisp-mode` , not `common-lisp-mode` , then

```
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys-for-major-mode 'lisp-mode "," 'slime-eval-defun)
```

just works.